# Firestore Custom Claim not updating UI

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm protecting my routes using custom claims that are created when a new user signs up.

```
allow read, write: if resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
```

However, when a new user signs up, it does not update custom claims to the UI! Meaning that a new user can't access the content unless he logout and login again, which is a really BROKEN experience.

In the docs, firebase team says they can force a UI update with this:

```
const metadataRef = admin.database().ref("metadata/" + user.uid);
return metadataRef.set({refreshTime: new Date().getTime()});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

I followed the code in both front/backend but I figured that this code only works with the realtime db, **not firestore**. There is no code to force UI to update with firestore in the docs - and all my attempts failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To refresh the token in a JavaScript **client** you do:

```
user.getIdToken(true)
```

There are equivalent calls for all other platforms, in case your client runs on those. But whatever the platform, you'll need to make this call to refresh the user's token so that it picks up the new/updated claim.

Doing this is completely independent of any other Firebase feature, so it doesn't depend on either Realtime Database or Firestore.

---

The JavaScript code you shared does not refresh the custom claims in the client, but is meant to run on the run on the trusted environment where you set the custom claim. The code merely marks in the Realtime Database when the user profile was last updated.

You'd then run another piece of code on the client that listens for this database value, and that forces the client to refresh the ID token of the user if the database flag changes.

That code is in the same documentation page you shared under [Client side implementation (JavaScript)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#defining_roles_via_firebase_functions_on_user_creation).